# Speed up simple Python function that uses list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm extracting 4 columns from an imported CSV file (~500MB) to be used for fitting a `scikit-learn` regression model.

It seems that this function used to do the extraction is extremely slow. I just learnt python today, any suggestions on how the function can be sped up?

Can multithreading/core be used? My system has 4 cores.

```
def splitData(jobs):
    salaries = [jobs[i]['salaryNormalized'] for i, v in enumerate(jobs)]
    descriptions = [jobs[i]['description'] + jobs[i]['normalizedLocation'] + jobs[i]['category'] for i, v in enumerate(jobs)]
    titles = [jobs[i]['title'] for i, v in enumerate(jobs)]

    return salaries, descriptions, titles
```

---

### Full Code

```
def loadData(filePath):
    reader = csv.reader( open(filePath) )
    rows = []

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        categories = ["id", "title", "description", "rawLocation", "normalizedLocation",
                        "contractType", "contractTime", "company", "category",
                        "salaryRaw", "salaryNormalized","sourceName"]

        # Skip header row
        if i != 0: 
            rows.append( dict(zip(categories, row)) )

    return rows



def splitData(jobs):
    salaries = []
    descriptions = []
    titles = []

    for i in xrange(len(jobs)):
        salaries.append( jobs[i]['salaryNormalized'] )
        descriptions.append( jobs[i]['description'] + jobs[i]['normalizedLocation'] + jobs[i]['category'] )
        titles.append( jobs[i]['title'] )

    return salaries, descriptions, titles



def fit(salaries, descriptions, titles):
    #Vectorize
    vect = TfidfVectorizer()
    vect2 = TfidfVectorizer()
    descriptions = vect.fit_transform(descriptions)
    titles = vect2.fit_transform(titles)

    #Fit
    X = hstack((descriptions, titles))
    y = [ np.log(float(salaries[i])) for i, v in enumerate(salaries) ]

    rr = Ridge(alpha=0.035)
    rr.fit(X, y)

    return vect, vect2, rr, X, y



jobs = loadData( paths['train_data_path'] )
salaries, descriptions, titles = splitData(jobs)
vect, vect2, rr, X_train, y_train = fit(salaries, descriptions, titles)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the `train_data_path`?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Sure: `http://www.mediafire.com/?4d3j8g88d6j2h0x`

Comment: Could you post a few lines of the data file directly in the question?

Comment: Please only state the code purpose in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def loadData(filePath):
    reader = csv.reader( open(filePath) )
    rows = []

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        categories = ["id", "title", "description", "rawLocation", "normalizedLocation",
                        "contractType", "contractTime", "company", "category",
                        "salaryRaw", "salaryNormalized","sourceName"]
```

A list like this should really be a global variable to avoid the expense of recreating it constantly. But you'd do better not store your stuff in a dictionary. Instead do this:

```
   for (id, title, description, raw_location, normalized_location, contract_type,
       contractTime, company, category, salary_raw, salary_normalized, source_name) in reader:

       yield salary_normalized, ''.join((description, normalized_location, category)), title
```

All the stuff is then stored in python local variables (fairly efficient). Then yield produces the three elements you are actually wanting. Just use

```
   salaries, descriptions, titles = zip(*loadData(...))
```

to get your three lists again

```
        # Skip header row
        if i != 0: 
            rows.append( dict(zip(categories, row)) )
```

Rather than this, call reader.next() before the loop to take out the header

```
    return rows
```

Comment: `loadtxt()` gives me the error `ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence` on line `X = np.array(X, dtype)`. Currently trying to upload the CSV somewhere

Comment: Here's the CSV: `http://www.mediafire.com/?4d3j8g88d6j2h0x`

Comment: @Nyxynyx, my bad. numpy doesn't handled quoted fields. Replaced my answer with a better one. My code processes the file in 8 seconds (does everything before the `fit` function).

Comment: It appears that I need to do `rows = zip( load_data(...) )` instead of `salaries, descriptions, titles = zip(loadData(...))`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Nyxynyx, typo. Should be `salaries, description, titles = zip(*loadData(...)))`. `zip(*...)` does the opposite of `zip(...)`

Answer (score 1):

`titles = [jobs[i]['title'] for i, v in enumerate(jobs)]` can (should?) be rewritten :

`titles = [j['title'] for j in jobs.items()]` 
because we just want to access the value at position i ([More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498132/how-to-iterate-over-values-in-dictionary-python))

Thus, the whole code would be :

```
def splitData(jobs):
    salaries = [j['salaryNormalized'] for j in jobs.items)]
    descriptions = [j['description'] + j['normalizedLocation'] + j['category'] for j in jobs.items)]
    titles = [j['title'] for j in jobs.items)]

    return salaries, descriptions, titles
```

Not quite sure how much it helps from a performance point of view.

Edit : Otherwise, another option might be to write a generator which returns `j['salaryNormalized'], j['description'] + j['normalizedLocation'] + j['category'], j['title']` as you need it. It depends how you use your function really.

Comment: I have updated the question with more code, that may help! How can I write the generator?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looping through the entire job data set 3 times (once each for salaries, descriptions and titles). You will be able to speed this up three-fold, if you extract all the info in one pass:

```
def split_data(jobs):
    for job, info in jobs.items():
        salaries.append(info['salaryNormalized'])
        descriptions.append([info['description'], 
                             info['normalizedLocation'], 
                             info['category']])
        titles.append(info['title'])
```

**EDIT** Added loadData(); slight tweak to return a dictionary of dictionaries, instead of a list of dictionaries:

```
def load_data(filepath):
    reader = csv.reader(open(filepath))
    jobs = {}

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        categories = ["id", "title", "description", "rawLocation", "normalizedLocation",
                        "contractType", "contractTime", "company", "category",
                        "salaryRaw", "salaryNormalized","sourceName"]

        if i != 0:
            jobs[i] = dict(zip(categories, row))

    return jobs
```

An example:

```
jobs = {0 : {'salaryNormalized' : 10000, 'description' : 'myKob',
             'normalizedLocation': 'Hawaii', 'category': 'categ1',
             'title' : 'tourist'},
        1 : {'salaryNormalized' : 15000, 'description' : 'myKob',
             'normalizedLocation': 'Hawaii', 'category': 'categ2',
             'title' : 'tourist'},
        2 : {'salaryNormalized' : 50000, 'description' : 'myKob',
             'normalizedLocation': 'Hawaii', 'category': 'categ10',
             'title' : 'resort_manager'}}

salaries, descriptions, titles = [], [], []
split_data(jobs)

print(salaries)
--> [10000, 15000, 50000]

print(descriptions)
--> [['myKob', 'Hawaii', 'categ1'], ['myKob', 'Hawaii', 'categ2'], ['myKob', 'Hawaii', 'categ10']]

print(titles)
--> ['tourist', 'tourist', 'resort_manager']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What makes you think that will speed it up three fold?

Comment: I am not suggesting that it will be exact, there will be some margin in that. Deductively, the original runs a loop through the data (~500MB) 3 times, that's expensive and dominates the time taken to run. This one only loops once. We have reduced the dominant factor by 3. 
My algorithm theory isn't perfect though - have I missed the mark on this one? Appreciate your thoughts

Comment: The problem is that your new loop does three times as much per iteration. It appends to a list three times, instead of 1. That means each iteration will take 3x the cost and your saving cancel completely out. Margins made it difficult to say which version will end up being faster.

Comment: That is a good point. However, original uses list comprehension to build the list one item at a time (though more efficiently than append) (total 3 'additions to list', for each entry in 500 MB). This version appends 3 times for one iteration (also therefore 3 calls to append for each entry in 500 MB). To me, that is the same number of append operations. Also kinda feel that the cost of appending is nominal compared the cost of looping  over 500 MB. What do you think?

Comment: Looping is actually fairly cheap. Its the appending which is expensive. That's why I'd expect both versions to have very similar speeds. Combining the loops reduces the looping overhead. Using a comprehension will be faster to append. Who wins out? I don't know. But I'm pretty sure there isn't a 3X difference.